# Express Server not responding on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have hosted an Express server on EC2. The server at http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 is accessible from any browser as well as Postman. But on making requests to the server from my React Frontend, I get a 404 error. How to resolve? I have already allowed cross-origin requests to my node server with the following code.

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

The same express server when running on my localhost responds perfectly fine to the request received from the React Frontend.

Edit: full server code added below.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var sendSomething = "error"
    res.send(sendSomething)
})
   
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server runs on port 3001')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is having the minimum structure as below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const http = require('http');

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("<html><div style='text-align:center;margin-top:20%'><h1>Welcome to My Page </h1></div></html>");
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(env.port, () => {
  console.log(`API is now live on ${env.port}`);
});
```

If yes then go to AWS console, services->vpc->security->security groups-> click on a security group id and make sure in the inbound rules source is '0.0.0./0'. (this means access is open for all ips. make sure to restrict this later.)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh404. Have added the full code in the main message. Has the same structure as u suggest. But still the same problem. The site is accessible in the browser and Postman, but can't make a GET request from another website (my react frontend). The inbound rules are set as u mentioned: 
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
HTTP TCP 80 ::/0
HTTPS TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS TCP 80 ::/0
The same server when hosted on my local machine, I can make the get request from my react frontend.

Comment: If it is accessible from browser and postman then your server is actually running. The issue should be with your front end.

Comment: But the exact same express backend when hosted on my desktop as http://localhost:xxxx, it can be accessed from my same React Frontend. Hence I am assuming the frontend to be functioning correctly. Could it be that there are CORS settings or equivalent required in the frontend as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your frontend IP (public IP) to the Inbound rules of the Express server? If you are able to access from local or postman, chances are you have added your IP to the inbound roules of the Express server instance but not the IP of the react frontend.